# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError using Scriptom 1.6 on Groovy 1.7.10

Tags: java, groovy, maven, ole, scriptom

I try to use scriptom 1.6 on Windows 7 to connect to excel application. However I keep getting the error:

```
Caught: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject does not implement the requested interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
    at GoBeby.main(GoBeby.groovy:14)
```

Here is my code:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject;

class GoExcel {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ActiveXObject excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application")
        excel.Visible = true;


    }
}
```

and maven file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.examples</groupId>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
    <artifactId>go_excel</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>

    <properties>
        <gmaven.version>1.2</gmaven.version>
        <groovy.version>1.7.10</groovy.version>     
        <slf4j.version>1.5.10</slf4j.version>   
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.version}</version>
        </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.13</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- scriptom -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.scriptom</groupId>
        <artifactId>scriptom</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
        <type>dll</type>
        <classifier>x64</classifier>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.3</version>
        <type>dll</type>
        <classifier>x86</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <!-- / scriptom -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>



    </repositories>

    <build>


        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <projectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core.groovyNature
                        </projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    </projectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I just run out of ideas. I have check to use jacob 64bit and 32 bit dll, change groovy framework to 1.5. Has anybody any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you are using 1.6.0 version of `scriptom` and 1.7.0 version of `groovy`. Looking at [scriptom pom](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/modules/scriptom/scriptom/1.6.0/scriptom-1.6.0.pom), it depends on `1.6.0` version of groovy.

Comment: Unfortunately Scriptom 1.6.0 does not work with groovy 1.6.0 either:  Caught: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class org.codehaus.groovy.scriptom.ActiveXObject does not implement the requested interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject
 at GoBeby.main(GoExcel.groovy:14). I just run out of ideas what can be wrong.